# Vuejs v-for on inline elements trims whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-for

When looping over an array (or object) with v-for on an inline element, vuejs does not render whitespace around said element.

For example, I have this html:

```
<div id="app">
    Vue Rendering<br>
    <a v-for="fruit in fruits" v-bind:href="fruit.url" v-html="fruit.label"></a>

    </div>
    <div>
    Navite rendering<br>
    <a href="apple.html">Apple</a>
    <a href="banana.html">Banana</a>
    <a href="peach.html">Peach</a>
</div>
```

and this javascript:

```
var fruits = [
    {
        label: 'Apple',
        url: 'apple.html'
    },
    {
        label: 'Banana',
        url: 'banana.html'
    },
    {
        label: 'Peach',
        url: 'peach.html'
    }
];

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        fruits: fruits
    }
});
```

When Vue renders this, it deletes the spaces between the links. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq4hc614/).

How can I counter this behaviour ?

Comment: The problem is when you iterate directly over the anchor, there's no whitespace to render. If you specfically *want* to render white space, you need to include it in the things to render like this https://jsfiddle.net/mq4hc614/2/. This might, however, be better handled with CSS.

Comment: It works fine this way, thank you. 
In case anyone reading this might not want an non breaking space (that's my case), you have to explicitly declare the white space with `&#32;`

Answer (score 12):

#### From the Docs on [List Rendering > `v-for` on a `<template>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt)

> Similar to template `v-if`, you can also use a `<template>` tag with `v-for` to render a block of multiple elements. For example:
>
> ```html
> <ul>
>  <template v-for="item in items">
>    <li>{{ item.msg }}</li>
>    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
>  </template>
> </ul>
> ```

So in order to get sibling elements (and yeah, a [*breaking* space character `&#32;`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0020) would count as one), you'll have to add the loop to a parent `<template>` container and then include any elements / spacing you want in the looped contents like this:

```html
<template v-for="fruit in fruits" >
  <span>{{fruit}}</span>&#32;
</template>
```

As of Vue 2.x+, templates trim any breaking space characters, even if they are escaped.

Instead, you can add a slot or text interpolation like this:

```html
<template v-for="fruit in fruits" >
  <span>{{fruit}}</span><slot> </slot>
</template>
```

```html
<template v-for="fruit in fruits" >
  <span>{{fruit}}</span>{{ ' ' }}
</template>
```

If you only want spaces *in-between* elements, you can output the space conditionally:

```html
<template v-for="(fruit, i) in fruits" >
  <span>{{fruit}}</span>{{ i < fruits.length -1 ? ', ': '' }}
</template>
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        fruits: ["apple", "banana", "carrot"]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <template v-for="(fruit, i) in fruits" >
      <span>{{fruit}}</span>{{ i < fruits.length -1 ? ', ': '' }}
    </template>
</div>
```

**Further Reading**:
[Issue #1841 - **Suggestion: v-glue / v-for element joins**](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1841)

Answer (score 2):

I had a case where I needed to wrap each character (including spaces) of a string in a `<span>` and solved it this way.

```
<template v-for="(letter, i) in 'My text with spaces'">
    <span v-if="letter !== ' '">{{ letter }}</span>
    <span v-else>&nbsp;</span>
</template>
```

Comment: This solution, although may seem dirty - is the only solution so far that work with sub-word units :)

Comment: By replacing breaking spaces with non-breaking spaces, the resulting text line will be non-breaking, which is usually not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```html
<a v-for="fruit in fruits" v-bind:href="fruit.url" v-html="fruit.label" 
   style="margin-right: 5px;"></a>
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but there are probably more semantic ways of resolving this (see above) that don't rely on inline styling.  Still, i'm sure it'll work for some folks