# How to use bootstrap to wrap elements across multiple tags?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap-5

### Solved:

This question is actually a combination of two individual questions:

1. how to generate an "article-like" passage when each sentence and each word is wrapped with a  tag. This should work naturally with Bootstrap's grid and container system, only if the spans around words are spaced (using space or linebreak) with each other. In other words, according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span#, the  tag "is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything" and two immediate adjacents s are considered as two different parts of a single word, i.e. doing is parsed as "doing" instead of "do" and "ing".
2. The  tags in my project code are generated using v-for of the VUE3, which by default doesn't provide any word-spacing between two s. So according to [Vuejs v-for on inline elements trims whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425255/vuejs-v-for-on-inline-elements-trims-whitespace#) i added some additional space between two word s by cooperating  and v-for. Especially i added a {{ ' ' }} spacing after each word . This semantically separates words and the line-wrapping takes place.

---

### Original question:

i'm currently learning Bootstrap by implementing a personal project. There i need to display a passage, of whom each sentence belongs to a tag. And again for each sentence, each individual token belongs to its own tag. Namely something like:

```
<span>
<span> the </span> <span> first </span> <span>sentence</span> <span>.</span>
</span>
<span>
<span> the </span> <span> second </span> <span>sentence</span> <span>!</span>
</span>
```

Now i would like to display this passage as a "real" article, where each sentence is displayed inline after its predecessor, namely something like:

> the first sentence . the
>
> second sentence !

Notice that the second sentence starts right after the period of the first one, and is wrapped because of lack of space.

Now I've learned to set `class='d-flex flex-sm-wrap'` to each sentence to break each individual sentence to be like:

> this is the first
>
> sentence .
>
> and here is the
>
> second sentence !

Each individual sentence breaks, but they are not displayed inline.

Could you please provide a solution to fulfill the requirement?

Also is there an elegant way of gapping the words? Is `class='pe-1'` for each word the best solution?

Edit on 30.12.2021, attach with a minimal runnable HTML snippet as suggested by Chris G:

Edit again on 30.12.2021, notice that there is no space nor returns between two adjacent words. It works perfectly here in the embedded console but doesn't work stand-along: https://jsfiddle.net/hv8c6wpf/10/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <span class="sentence d-flex flex-sm-wrap pe-1">
              <span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span>
      </span>
      <span class="sentence d-flex flex-sm-wrap pe-1">
              <span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the actual HTML you're using, ideally as [mre]. Also, making a sentence wrapper a flex container is not really what you want, according to your requirement.

Comment: I think the problem is in the HTML code. why not wrap all content in one P tag and style what you need inside spans ?

Comment: @AhmedElbessfy Indeed that will save a lot of effort. But what i want is to 1. edit the property of each individual word (e.g. marking with different colors according to their POS) and 2. each sentence should be operatable (e.g. bolding-up by hovering).

Comment: @ChrisG The question is updated, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Again: why deliberately remove the layout you want by using flex styles? https://jsfiddle.net/zs1t5evm/

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG, your code snippet indeed works and it makes me realize that i used the wrong snippet. The <span>s wrapping words are rendered using VUE3 and there is no returns between them, will update the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need extra flex or anything, just wrapping each sentence with a `span` and each word with a `span` works fine.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span>
          <span>This</span>
          <span>is</span>
          <span>the</span>
          <span>first</span>
          <span>sentence.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>This</span>
          <span>is</span>
          <span>the</span>
          <span>second</span>
          <span>sentence.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>This</span>
          <span>is</span>
          <span>the</span>
          <span>third</span>
          <span>sentence.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>This</span>
          <span>is</span>
          <span>the</span>
          <span>fourth</span>
          <span>sentence.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>This</span>
          <span>is</span>
          <span>the</span>
          <span>fifth</span>
          <span>sentence.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>This</span>
          <span>is</span>
          <span>the</span>
          <span>sixth</span>
          <span>sentence.</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Every sentence wraps after the width of the `col-sm-3` is wrapped. Is this what you want?

Comment: It is indeed, i realized the problem is that my code snippet is misleading and doesn't match the real situation. Am working on updating.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  the class **d-inline**? If I have understood you properly, then you are trying to implement word-wrap through bootstrap.
Anyways, you should definetly try adding classes via Chrome dev tools because it lists all the related bootstrap classes while also displaying how they change the page.

Use **px-1 or mx-1** : for spacing words within a sentence.

[image: DevTools]

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for answering. I tried to attach d-inline to row, col-sm-3, and even to the container <div>, unfortunately, none of them works...